Are questions regarding Geogebra allowed here, or should they be asked on SO?
Question:

Are questions regarding Geogebra allowed here, or should they be asked on SO?

I have a problem currently with trying to plot a certain function $f(x,y)$ in Geogebra which contains both real and imaginary parts, which Geogebra can handle to the best of my knowledge.
In this case, my question is about how I should go about (or what I am doing wrong when) plotting this specific function.
Seeing that there currently no geogebra tag currently, I would like to know if questions regarding Geogebra would be considered allowed here, or if I should post on SO instead (where there exists a [geogebra] tag).

If it is a math question, ask here. Is it is an implementation question, do not ask here.

@XanderHenderson Sorry if I am missing something, but wouldn't having trouble plotting a function fall under implementation?

Yes, it very likely would fall under the general umbrella of "implementation".  Which would make it off-topic here.  (Which is not to say that it would be on-topic on SO, but such a question is not on-topic here.)

I'm not a Geogebra user, but I'd first try posing a "how do I do this" type query at the Geogebra help center.

There is an older question: Can I ask Geogebra questions on this site? It has no answers at the moment, but one of the comments links to this question: Do we actually "welcome questions about: • Software that mathematicians use"?

Are you aware that Geogebra has the functions re() (for the real) and im() (for the imaginary part) of complex numbers?

@Dominique Thank you, that seems to be what I was missing. Despite Geogebra lagging "a bit" when trying to render the equation/trying to adjust the axis, it is still very helpful :)

Also sorry for not mentioning that I had posted a question on Meta.SE a bit after I posted this, I was just trying to see if I could get any answers on there (to then post here) since the [site-recommendation] tag exists.

Excuse me but what exactly is geogebra?

@YourLordJoyBoy It's a math software that some mathematicians use, although it's usually used on higher-end computers (not like the Chromebook) due to it being extremely laggy on low end devices when trying to adjust the graph or input functions.

So it's software? But its not too reliable for the most part? If I'm wrong on that I apologize, this is the first I've heard of it.

Answer to my question about this on Meta.SE for reference
From the comments here:

[4] If it is a math question, ask here. I[f] it is an implementation question, do not ask here. -Xander Henderson [Mod] Apr 9 at 20:56
[5] Yes, it very likely would fall under the general umbrella of "implementation". Which would make it off-topic here. (Which is not to say that it would be on-topic on SO, but such a question is not on-topic here.) -Xander Henderson [Mod] Apr 9 at 21:07


So in general:

This type of question should be asked on SO if it is a specific implementation question (i.e. a programming problem with Geogebra)
As @hardmath noted and as noted in an earlier Math.SE Meta post (linked by @MartinSleziak), I could also post a query like "how do I plot ___" in the Geogebra help center.


Overall:

If it is a math problem, ask on Math.SE.
If it is a specific implementation problem that is giving me trouble, ask on SO.
If it is a "how do I plot ___" question, post it in the Geogebra help center.

